# I want to use rxjs subject to detect the value change in multiple components. But it only shows change in the component which changes it

Tags: javascript, angular, service, rxjs, observable

I'm using different module so it can be used in lazy loaded modules.
here is my service file.

```js
import {NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ChangeEventService {

    public invokeEvent:Subject<any> = new Subject();
    //    localId:any = { name:'', eventId:0, orgId:0};
    constructor() {
     
    }

    public callComponent(currentId:any):void {
      console.log("Invoked");
      this.invokeEvent.next({localId:currentId});
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [   ],
  exports : [
  ],
  providers: [ ChangeEventService ],
})
export class ChangeEventModule { }
```

subscription to Rxjs subject is only changing in the component/service which changes It.

```js
export class xyz {
    constructor(private change: ChangeEventService) { 
                    this.change.invokeEvent.subscribe((value) => {
                        this.event = value.localId;
                        console.log("I'm chnaged...!!");
                    });
    }

    
    anyFunction(eventdata:any) {
            this.change.callComponent(eventdata);
     }
 }
```

I get the updated value only In the component which change the value of invokeEvent.

Comment: Can you check how often the constructor is run. You might have multiple instances of the `ChangeEventService`.

Comment: is `this.change.invokeEvent.callComponent(eventdata);` suppose to be `this.change.callComponent(eventdata);`

Comment: @shusson: +1. Also, are you sure `ChangeEventService` is a singleton? Is it declared in `NgModule.providers` of a module that is **eagerly loaded** (vs lazily-loaded)?

Comment: @shusson I did mistake in copying code here thx for pointing that out.

Comment: @Philipp I'm calling it in 2 different components of 2 different module where one is lazy loadedinside the router outlet of another module. will it create multiple instances?

Comment: @AngularFrance I'm importing ChangeEventModule in all lazy loaded modules.

Comment: @YASHDAVE. Hmmm. I'm assuming `ChangeEventModule` is also exporting things then? If you're importing `ChangeEventModule` only to make `ChangeEventService` available to your lazy-loaded modules, then there's no need. Providers have a global scope by default.

Comment: @AngularFrance okay I'll try that. SO I'll need to define it in one provider only?

Comment: Exactly! But it MUST BE in the providers of a module that is loaded *eagerly* at bootstrap (i.e. either `AppModule` or a module imported by `AppModule`).

Comment: @AngularFrance now i'm getting DI error and it says "Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ChangeEventService!"

Comment: In the providers of which module did you declare `ChangeEventService`?

Comment: @AngularFrance currently none. I've included it in bootstrap to make singleton but I guess this doesn't work in lazy load so now I'm trying to use "https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1071" this method. will let u know if it works.

Comment: You lost me... `ChangeEventService` should be declared **the same way** it is in the code you provided. I only suggested that you moved the declaration to another module...

Comment: @AngularFrance that's not working since my all modules are lazy loaded.

Comment: Impossible. The root module (aka `AppModule`) is NEVER lazy-loaded.

Comment: @AngularFrance I know but that  it's giving me DI error in lazy loaded modules.

Comment: @AngularFrance this is what i'm getting after following your steps.

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for EventsComponent: ([object Object], ?). ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber: Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack: Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString: createMethodProperty/props[key].value(), 4 more… }

Comment: Difficult to help you further without seeing the actual app

Comment: @AngularFrance can u give me ur email ID or mail me on yashndave@gmail.com I'll share my screen on teamviewer. thx in advance

Comment: @AngularFrance sorry for wasting ur time,  I forgot to compile ts file after changes :P Now I'm removing my question

Comment: @AngularFrance It's working every time except 1st time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 
@Philipp commented I was creating multiple instances of my service by providing it in multiple modules.
And as suggested by @AngularFrance I declared in it provider of app.module(1st module of my app). than I was not getting updated value in any subscription ( except the one which was calling callComponent ) 1st time.So I used BehaviorSubject and gave it any random initial value. So now it's sending initial value to one component at initial time and than it's sending updated value to all subscribers when it's updated.

So I guess that solved my problem.